# Pusher Integration

Tags: javascript, php, pusher

Anybody using pusher with php / javascript? I have a web app using the old polling method, in php on the server side and javascript / ajax polling on the client side. Everything works great but I wanted to try out Pusher.

I made it work so that I send info on a channel and the javascript client receives it and does something but my question is this:

How do you load the html page for the first time and set everything up before starting to get info on the channel? what I meand is, for example, a chat app, when you go into a chatroom web page, before you start getting new messages, how do you get the messages that were sent before (chat history)? some sort of ajax polling to setup everything up and then start listening to the pusher channel?

Hope anybody out there that has implemented pusher can help me out on this basic concept.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pusher guarantees realtime functionalities and delivers messages to the channel only.

So for the chat history, you need to save all message to database and load all of them back from database.

> How do you load the html page for the first time and set everything up
>   before starting to get info on the channel?

At the first time, when the page is loaded, you need to use Javascript (Ajax) to setup the connection, subscribe to a channel and bind to events. You also need to get the chat history (from Database) then append to your view.

Comment: Good job! Other will review too, see the last link named *From review* from my first message.

Comment: @DucFilan so first I would need to do a normal POLL using ajax as usual, then all the pusher steps to subscribe and start getting new messages, right? (instead of polling every X seconds as before)

Comment: The steps should be:
1. Get chat history and show up
2. Client A and B subscribe and bind to events
3. Client A uses ajax to request to server (To save message to DB), and inside the server method, trigger events
4. Client B get the message, then show it up to the view using javascript